# Command do not end

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

Gitlab runner doesn't give any output or error. It just stays at loading screen forever when run this command

```
python manage.py test
```

[image: Loadin...]

```
image: python:3.6

services:
  - postgres:10

before_script:
  - apt-get update
  - pip install pipenv
  - pipenv install --system --deploy --ignore-pipfile

stages:
  - test

test:
  script:
     - export DATABASE_URL=postgres://postgres:@postgres:5432/test-master-tool
     - python manage.py migrate
     - python manage.py test
     - coverage report
```

Comment: Is assume a firewall blocking the update. How long have you been running it?

Comment: Even thou it should take a few minutes to run all test but this is going on for more than 20 minutes, I've stopped it after that.

Comment: Also I am using shared runner provided by gitlab.